# Nested dictionaries from csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, nested-loops

I am stuck on this problem. I have some data in a csv that when read looks like:

```
Example Data
['', 'Name', 'Phone', 'Address', 'City', 'Country', 'Email']
['1', 'Bob Myers', '410-504-5887', '12334 Hamilton Way', 'Toronto', 'Canada', 'bob@gmail.com']
['2', 'Carlton James', '455-323-8479', '1234 James Rd', 'New York', 'USA', 'carlton@example.com']
['3', 'Frank Wright', '744-521-9874', '567 Travis St', 'Boston', 'USA', 'fw4322@yahoo.com']
```

Which I would like to make look like this:

```
my_dict = {{'Name': {1: 'Bob Myers', 2: 'Carlton James', 3: 'Frank Wright'}}, 
 {'Phone': {1: '410-504-5887', 2: '455-323-8479', 3: '744-521-9874'}}, 
 {'Address': {1: '12334 Hamilton Way', 2: '1234 James Rd', 3: '567 Travis St'}},
 {'City': {1: 'Toronto', 2: 'New York', 3: 'Boston'}},
 {'Country': {1: 'Canada', 2: 'USA', 3: 'USA'}},
 {'Email': {1: 'bob@gmail.com', 2: 'carlton@example.com', 3: 'fw4322@yahoo.com'}}
}
```

I wrote a script to do so but my script only returns the last item in the row, like so:

```
import csv
f = csv.DictReader(open('data.csv'))

result = {}
for row in f:
    key = row.pop('')
    for i in row:
        result[key] = row[i]
print(result)

-------:

{'1': 'bob@gmail.com', '2': 'carlton@example.com', '3': 'fw4322@yahoo.com'}
```

How do I adjust my script to iterate through all of the indices in all of the rows?

I cannot use pandas.

Comment: Rows from a DictReader won't look like your example. If you printed the rows, they would be `dict`, not list. I'm not sure where your example data comes from, its not a CSV, but it is what a csv would look like when read by `csv.reader`. It would be better to post the actual CSV lines as the Example Data so that we can run it with your code.

Comment: Yes. That is what it looks like when read. I edited the comment to reflect that.

Comment: that's what the file looks like? Then its not a CSV. It looks like lines of json or perhaps python lists printed as strings. If you read this file as DictReader, they will be `{"[''": "['1'", " 'Name'": " 'Bob Myers'", " 'Phone'": " '410-504-5887'", " 'Address'": " '12334 Hamilton Way'", " 'City'": " 'Toronto'", " 'Country'": " 'Canada'", " 'Email']": " 'bob@gmail.com']"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv.DictReader()` returns an `OrderedDict`, so the key to solving this problem is to access your values with standard dictionary methods. This approach provides the desired result:

```py
import csv

f = csv.DictReader(open('data.csv'))


result = {}
for i, row in enumerate(f, start=1):
    row.pop('')
    if i == 1:
        for key, value in row.items():
            result[key] = {}
            result[key][i] = value
    else:
        for key, value in row.items():
            result[key][i] = value
    
print(result)
```

Out:

```
{'Name': {1: 'Bob Myers', 2: 'Carlton James', 3: ' Frank Wright'}, 
 'Phone': {1: ' 410-504-5887', 2: ' 455-323-8479', 3: ' 744-521-9874'}, 
 'Address': {1: '12334 Hamilton Way', 2: ' 1234 James Rd', 3: ' 567 Travis St'}, 
 'City': {1: ' Toronto', 2: ' New York', 3: ' Boston'}, 
 'Country': {1: ' Canada', 2: ' USA', 3: ' USA'}, 
 'Email': {1: ' bob@gmail.com', 2: ' carlton@example.com', 3: ' sdfa@yahoo.com'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are iterating over all indices, the problem is that you have only one dict with the keys '1', '2' and '3' and you are changing the values related to this keys. Maybe you should create one dict to each column. You can use `reader.fieldnames` to get the column names and you can do

```
for field in reader.fieldnames:
    result[field] = {}
```

to create the first dictionary. Then you iterate over each row and add each value to the right dict from result